# Pandas: OverflowError when trying to create a new df column using a long-int value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, long-integer

I have a dataframe as such

```
      ID       NAME  group_id
0     205292   A     183144058824253894513539088231878865676           
1     475121   B     183144058824253894513539088231878865676
1     475129   C     183144058824253894513539088231878865676
```

I want to transform it such that row 0 is linked to the other rows in the following way

```
   LinkedBy  By_Id    LinkedTo  To_Id   group_id
1  A         205292   B         475121  183144058824253894513539088231878865676
2  A         205292   C         475129  183144058824253894513539088231878865676
```

Basically, I am compressing the first dataframe by linking 0th index row against all other such that an n row df will give me a (n-1) row df. I can accomplish this without the group id (which is of type long and stays constant) by the following code:

```
pd.DataFrame({"LinkedBy": df['NAME'].iloc[0],"By_Id": df['ID'].iloc[0],"LinkedTo":df['NAME'].iloc[1:],"To_Id":df['ID'].iloc[1:]})
```

But I am facing problems while adding a group id. When I do the following

```
pd.DataFrame({"LinkedBy": df['NAME'].iloc[0],"By_Id": df['ID'].iloc[0],"LinkedTo":df['NAME'].iloc[1:],"To_Id":df['ID'].iloc[1:],"GroupId":df['potential_group_id'].iloc[0]})
```

I get `OverflowError: long too big to convert`

How do I add the group_id of type long to my new df.

Comment: can it just be a `str` instead which should work? so basically cast the dtype using `.astype(str)`

Comment: I suspect this is because you are passing arrays of different sizes. This introduces NaNs, which forces to float and you cannot have that big of floats. If it is not cruical, I agree that str would be a better choice.

Comment: Ideally, I would like to keep them as Long. I would like to know what happens in the background while trying to create this df that gives the error and if there's another way to skin the cat so to speak

Comment: The problem is in the dict. `"LinkedBy": df['NAME'].iloc[0]` this has only one entry but `"LinkedTo": df['NAME'].iloc[1:]` this one has two. Instead of `[A]` you need to pass `[A, A]`. Maybe with `2* [df['NAME'].iloc[0]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `group_id` in all rows appears to be the same, you could try this:

```
res = pd.merge(left=df.iloc[0,:], right=df.iloc[1:,:], how='right', on=['group_id'])
res.columns = ['By_Id', 'LinkedBy', 'group_id', 'To_Id', 'LinkedTo']
```

Note that this will only work when `group_id` can be used as your join key.

Answer (score 0):

- `groupby` everything and then `apply` with custom function
- `cond1` make sure `'group_id'` matches
- `cond2` make sure `'NAME'` does not match
- subset `df` in `apply` function
- `rename` and `drop` stuff
- more renaming and dropping and resetting

---

```
def find_grp(x):
    cond1 = df.group_id == x.name[2]
    cond2 = df.NAME != x.name[1]
    temp = df[cond1 & cond2]
    rnm = dict(ID='To_ID', NAME='LinkedTo')
    return temp.drop('group_id', axis=1).rename(columns=rnm)


cols = ['ID', 'NAME', 'group_id']
df1 = df.groupby(cols).apply(find_grp)
df1.index = df1.index.droplevel(-1)
df1.rename_axis(['By_ID', 'LinkedBy', 'group_id']).reset_index()
```

[image]

---

***OR***

```
df1 = df.merge(df, on='group_id', suffixes=('_By', '_To'))
df1 = df1[df1.NAME_By != df1.NAME_To]

rnm = dict(ID_By='By_ID', ID_To='To_ID', NAME_To='LinkedTo', NAME_By='LinkedBy')

df1.rename(columns=rnm)
```

[image]